# How can I dynamically change the color of a label's text in Xamarin C#?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what I tried. Changing in the constructor works but I cannot seem to change dynamically.

```
    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        correctButton.Clicked += correctButtonClicked;
        resetButton.Clicked += resetButtonClicked;
        faveLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        faveLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => FaveLabelTapped())
        });
        // this works
        faveLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;

    }

    void FaveLabelTapped()
    {
        AS.phrase.Favorite = !AS.phrase.Favorite;
        if (AS.phrase.Favorite) {
            // this gives an error
            faveLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
        } else {
            faveLabel.TextColor = Color.Yello;
        }
        App.DB.UpdateFavorite(AS.phrase.Favorite, AS.phrase.PhraseId);
    }
```

Gives me a message

> Color doesn't exist in the current context

Can someone give me some ideas as to how I can change from inside the FaveLabelTapped method?

Comment: You may want to use binding for this

Comment: Is there a simple way I could do this with binding?  The way I have seems pretty easy if it worked when in another method.

Comment: Have you included the required `using` statements for the `Xamarin.Forms` _namespace_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really stuggling, why can't you just do something like this:

```
    public PhrasesFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        correctButton.Clicked += correctButtonClicked;
        resetButton.Clicked += resetButtonClicked;
        faveLabel.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        faveLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => 
            {
                 AS.phrase.Favorite = !AS.phrase.Favorite;
                 if (AS.phrase.Favorite) 
                 {
                      faveLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
                 }

                 App.DB.UpdateFavorite(AS.phrase.Favorite, AS.phrase.PhraseId);
            })
        });
    }
```

Creating your command at the same point that you assign it allows you to correctly associate the pointer to the label. Also unless you care about using the method 'FaveLabelTapped()' elsewhere then there's no major need to have it refactored into its own method.

EDIT:

It's possible it's not resolving the reference to the 'Color' class correctly at runtime, so you could also try:

```
void FaveLabelTapped()
{
    AS.phrase.Favorite = !AS.phrase.Favorite;
    if (AS.phrase.Favorite) {
        // this gives an error
        faveLabel.TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Red; //Change this to include the assembly reference.
    }
    App.DB.UpdateFavorite(AS.phrase.Favorite, AS.phrase.PhraseId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try that out.  But not sure why the other way would not work.  The reason for doing this in a method was a don't want to split functionality among different files each with this partial class.  Do you have any idea why moving it out to a method would stop the Color assignment working?

Comment: There could be a runtime conflict, is there an assembly your referencing in your derived class that contains a propert called 'Color'?